# Why is the version (__v) field in MongoDB always 0?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

The title says it all.  Why is the version field in a MongoDB document always 0?  I've updated fields, and added new fields, to documents several times... and called the `save()` method countless times... but the value is never updated.

Comment: It's only used for tracking changes to array fields. Have you changed any of those?

Comment: Huh?  The field is at the top-most level in the document.  Are you saying that it does NOT reflect changes to the document itself?  Updating ANY field means the document is no longer the same version as it was originally.

Comment: It's only used to track changes to the array fields of the document for use in optimistic concurrency control. See [here](http://aaronheckmann.tumblr.com/post/48943525537/mongoose-v3-part-1-versioning) for an overview as there's not much in the docs themselves.